# Namespace 'Smo' not found, although the reference is added

Tags: c#, assemblies

I have added Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.dll reference to my project, but it still gives me the error below. The referenced dll is in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies path.

Error   25  The type or namespace name 'Smo' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

All the classes that I use such as Restore, Serer class under the Smo namesapce also throws the error.

Please advise.

Comment: Please do spellcheck,that might be a reason!!!

Comment: Yes I added using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Comment: Are you sure that the DLL is both compiled into the right settings for your project? IE certain x86 only DLLs cause all kinds of errors for x64 applications.

Comment: Did you get intellisense on the namespace as you were adding the using statement?

Comment: I need to use Restore and Serve class which are available  only in /microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo namespace. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where are you consuming this from?  Any chance you're using the client profile (under project properties -> Application -> Target Framework)?  I've been caught out a number of times by that.  If that's the case, it's usually as simple as selecting a non-client profile framework version.

Anyway, can we get some more detail about what kind of solution this is?

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same problem, I noticed my project was targeting framework 3.

Changing to 3.5 or 4 helped solve the problem.

My reference are to

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add all 4 dlls ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx)):

> Most of the classes
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
>   namespace resides in the
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll and
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
>   files. Additionally, some of the
>   enumeration classes are in the
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll and
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum.dll
>   assembly files. **You will have to
>   import all four files to access all of
>   the classes in the
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
>   namespace**

Comment: I added all the references that you stated about, but in the code it does not recognize 'Smo' when i add [using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo] statement;

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 then

Add References
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo
Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo
Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum
Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum

if still u got error
then add two more dll

microsoft.sqlserver.SmoEx...
Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfoEx...

---

Hope it will work

Thank you.

Comment: I added all the references that you stated about, but in the code it does not recognize 'Smo' when i add [using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo] statement;

Answer (score 1):

add reference to "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll" from "`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`" will eliminate this error.